# How to receive simultaneously converted and raw request body on spring mvc

Tags: java, spring, rest, spring-mvc

I have implemented Jaxb2RootElementHttpMessageConverter for converting XML request to my java object and it works. My controller looks like

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/post", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public MyResponse post(@RequestBody MyRequest request, BindingResult result)
```

I want to recieve simultaneously raw xml request for storing logs and converted java object for validation and another processes like

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/post", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public MyResponse post(@RequestBody String originalRequest, @RequestBody @Valid MyRequest request, BindingResult result)
```

I have tried to get response body as HttpServletRequest's InputStream, but I got `IOException: Stream closed`

How to do it if I want so Spring make transformation and validation instead of my code?

Comment: The way the controller method in the example is structured, two separate in-built `HttpMessageConverter`s will be required - `StringHttpMessageConverter` for the `String` argument and `Jaxb2RootElementHttpMessageConverter` for the `MyRequest` argument. However, the default Spring MVC implementation terminates request processing at the first message converter that can read a request successfully (see `AbstractMessageConverterMethodArgumentResolver`). Therefore, you won't be able to populate two different method arguments with the same request with the default implementation.

Comment: @manish Thanks, but I'm asking about a little different things how to receive from 'Jaxb2RootElementHttpMessageConverter' original and converted messages.

Comment: You cannot. `MessageConverter`s do not give you the raw text. You can marshal the request as either a `String` or an `Object` in a controller method and then generate the other using some sort of a utility function to convert that into the other.