# @RequestBody map to object and get raw request string simultaneously

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc

I have use @RequestBody for mapping request to object at rest controller, but in the same time I need to get raw JSON from request without mapping. I don't map all JSON content to
object. How to get  simultaneously JSON raw and JSON mapped to object

```
 @RequestMapping(path = "/rest/web")
    public ResponseEntity<String> paymentHook( @RequestBody UserReq request, BindingResult bindingResult)
```

I can just get raw like this `@RequestBody` String payload, but then I must parse content "by hand"

Comment: Similar question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41266547/how-to-receive-simultaneously-converted-and-raw-request-body-on-spring-mvc

Answer (score 0):

```
**You can parse your JSON raw data to JSONObject and simply get all keys**

String mockResponse = "{\"customer\":{\"id\":34,\"email\":\"tt@gmail.com\"}\"}";
JSONObject jsonResponse = JSONObject.fromObject(mockResponse);
```

Comment: it's simple with simple json

Comment: You can use complex JSON in the same way.